# Constraints not updated in swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, constraints, swift5

I have a TableView. This TableView contains cells that can have a video or not, a title and a description. 
I can test that with a string. if str == "video" -> I have a video
If there is a video the cell is like that: Video on top, then the title, and then the description. If there is not, the same but but without the video (so the title must be on top)

When I load a cell with a video, it's working perfectly.
When I load then a cell without a video, it's working again, the video is not here anymore.
But, when a reload a cell with a video (the first cell for example), the video is not here anymore. It's like the constraint is not updated anymore.

This is my code (inside the TableViewCell):

```
// BgCellView is a background view in my Cell & WebView the youtube video
bgCellView.addSubview(webView)
webView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgCellView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgCellView.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgCellView.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgCellView.leftAnchor, constant: marginLeftAndRight).isActive = true
titleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgCellView.rightAnchor, constant: -marginLeftAndRight).isActive = true

if str == "video" {
titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: webView.bottomAnchor, constant: 14).isActive = true
}
else {
titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgCellView.topAnchor, constant: 14).isActive = true
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Where do you set up all this constraints?

Comment: var info: Info? {
      didSet {
         updateTableView()
      }
   }
Inside this function

Comment: Does your property `info` assign inside `dequeueReusableCell`?

Comment: Yes, inside the cellForRowAt function

Comment: Post all of the code for your cell. You aren't sharing enough info.

Comment: When `cellForRowAt` gets called, you re-adding again `webView` to your `bgCellView` and re-added constraint to `webView`. So for example if it gets called 3 times, your cell has 3 `webView`. I think you get an idea. Try to debug and print constraints and views inside your `UITableViewCell`